# Receive data from the server C# to client delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, tcp, vcl, indy10

I want to link the **tcp** server programming with **C#** and **TCPCLIENT** in Delphi.
How I can receive the data from the server when the client send a request for more explains in want to receive the response from the server I use every method but the data is empty.

C#

```
private Dictionary<string, Message> _networkStreams = new Dictionary<string, Message>();
    private void SimpleTcpClientOnDataReceived(object sender, Message e)
            {
                string Data = e.MessageString.Replace("\u0013", "");
                Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(Data);
                Message message = _networkStreams[request.RequestId];
                message.Reply(request.Data);
            }
```

Delphi Code

```
procedure TfrmList.btnsortClick(Sender: TObject);
var Request:TRequest;
  I: Integer;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  ArrayElement: TJSonValue ;
  JSonValue: TJSonValue;
  item:TListItem;

begin

      Request := TRequest.Create;
      Request.Link := '/GetAll';
      Request.Password := 'Password';
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Request));
      Memo1.Text  := Memo1.Lines.Add(IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLnWait(600));

end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear. Try to use google translate with simple short sentences.

Comment: I change the question please help me :D

Comment: It looks like your protocol has no link control (like transmition of markers , message length prior payload, etc). Probably server expects new line at the end of serialized message ? If this is the case then try to add line ```IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write('\n');``` after sending of serialized json message. Use debugger at server side to see whether server receive message at all and sends response. Also usage of sniffer could allow you to figure out who is culprit(client/server) very fast

Comment: Hello @MaximSagaydachny this is not work  `IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write('\n');`
i try also this but is not work 

`string replyMessage = String.Format("You said {0}", e.MessageString); //This is the reply message
            e.ReplyLine(replyMessage); //Send reply message back to client.
            e.Reply("Hello User");
            return;`

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny the client is sending JSON, which is a self-delimiting format, so sending a terminator like a link break is not strictly necessary (also, FYI, the IOHandler has a `WriteLn()` method). But without knowing exactly what format the server is expecting, or what format exactly it sends back, there is no way to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send (LF) or (#10) at the end of the message

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Request));
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(#10);
Memo1.Text  := Memo1.Lines.Add(IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLnWait(600));
```